How do I restore an old iPhone without getting stuck in Recovery Mode?

I've tried to restore this iPhone multiple times to no avail. It either doesn't download the update or the iPhone resets itself while the update is downloading. Is there any way I could restore it without the update? Without iTunes too?

Welcome to Ask Different. Which is the model of your iPhone? Which macOS is your Mac using?

You need some basic troubleshooting here to be honest.

Does this computer work to restore other devices
Eliminate a cabling issue (network cable on the Mac, take the Mac to a new network) and a network issue.
Consult a specific Apple troubleshooting article for your exact version of macOS (since you say you’re without iTunes)
Take that phone to another computer to restore.


What iphone model is it ? I would try DFU mode. Read this. https://www.ifixit.com/News/41428/everything-you-need-to-know-about-dfu-mode-for-ios-devices

How do you think the phone not being in DFU mode is affecting the Mac’s ability to download the update?

Wrong answers are better than a clarifying comment in the answer section. Perhaps  editing your post to complete your theory would avoid deletion votes.  Right answers are often surprising or reveal a twist that most saw coming or weren’t even listed in the question (initially or ever).  Mostly I was curious if you had experience with that exact screen and a phone that caused this without being in DFU mode….
